# No dimension available for SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH and SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA, and the workaround of giving a tolerance instead doesn't work

Tags: oracle, gis, oracle12c, oracle-spatial

We currently run an `ArcGIS Server` over an `Oracle 12c` database. The GIS software handles the database itself, but we would like to do measurements on some values its tables contains.

Me, I would like to list the length of some lines contained in the geometry field (shape) of a table, but I don't succeed.

```sql
select * from TRONCON;
-- ok. Runs fine.

SELECT c.cur, SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH(c.shape, m.diminfo) 
  FROM TRONCON c, user_sdo_geom_metadata m 
  WHERE m.table_name = 'TRONCON' AND m.column_name = 'SHAPE';

-- Fails with this error message :
-- ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SDO_LENGTH'
-- 06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
-- *Cause:    
-- *Action:

select * from user_sdo_geom_metadata;
-- Appears empty.

select * from all_sdo_geom_metadata;
-- Appears empty.
```

Because we aren't the ones who are filling the database with data (this is the responsability of the GIS software to manage data and perform structural changes in the schema, if needed) we don't know why the `user_sdo_geom_metadata` and the `all_sdo_geom_metadata` tables are empty, and how to regenerate them if it can be done. Because [this case is unexpected](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geom-sdo_length.htm#SPATL1120).

A colleague wants to measure an area, and encounters the same kind of problems with an attempt of replacing the missing dimension by a tolerance :

```sql
SELECT sdo_geom.sdo_area(SHAPE, 0.005, 'unit=hectare') FROM ZONE_INTERET;

-- ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SDO_AREA'
-- 06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
```

How can we make these functions working ?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` table is not filled is surprising. ArcGIS is fairly well integrated with Oracle Spatial and does a good job of maintaining that information. Whenever you define a new feature class (using ArcCatalog), you should see a new row in that table. If it is missing, then you are unable to define any spatial index on the data, which would make all queries (including viewing) very slow.

What may be happening is that you are connecting as a different user than the ArcGIS applications ? `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` (like `USER_TABLES`) is for the currently connected user. `ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` (just like `ALL_TABLES`) is for all the tables accessible by the current user (in other schemas).

Then again you do not need the info in that table when invoking spatial functions: you can just manually pass a tolerance value. In more recent versions (18.1 and later), the tolerance is actually optional: we pick a default value.

Here are some examples:

```
SQL> SELECT sdo_geom.sdo_area(geom, 0.005, 'unit=hectare') FROM us_counties where id=1;

SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(GEOM,0.005,'UNIT=HECTARE')
--------------------------------------------
                                  156486.874
1 row selected.

SQL> SELECT sdo_geom.sdo_length(geom, 0.005, 'unit=km') FROM us_interstates where id=1;

SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH(GEOM,0.005,'UNIT=KM')
-----------------------------------------
                               3956.18879
1 row selected.
```

The syntax error you get (ORA-06553) is very odd. Try describing the package:

```
describe sdo_geom
```

This produces a large output. But in there you should see the two signatures for `SDO_LENGTH`:

```
FUNCTION SDO_LENGTH RETURNS NUMBER
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 GEOM                           SDO_GEOMETRY            IN
 DIM                            SDO_DIM_ARRAY           IN
 UNIT                           VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 COUNT_SHARED_EDGES             NUMBER                  IN     DEFAULT

FUNCTION SDO_LENGTH RETURNS NUMBER
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 GEOM                           SDO_GEOMETRY            IN
 TOL                            NUMBER                  IN     DEFAULT
 UNIT                           VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 COUNT_SHARED_EDGES             NUMBER                  IN     DEFAULT
```

Is this what you see ?